Old man in antiques-shop, 3(?) separate stories, wedding-cake figures
I'm looking for a horror(?)-movie, probably from the early 1980s.
It's about an old man and his antiques-shop, where every item has a story - and a little surprse.  The movie tells (I think) three such stories, about three people who bought an item in the shop - and what happened to them afterwards.  The old man acts as narrator, stitching the stories together.
One is about a young couple about to get married.  Not sure what they bought, but possibly one of thouse figurines of a couple, that goes on-top of a wedding-cake... or maybe a knife/knife-set.  At the end of this sub-story they're about to cut their wedding-cake together when...

 the woman "accidently" cuts the male figurine in the head, and it starts to bleed... so does her husbands head.

I don't remember the two(?) other sub-stories.
Throughout the movie there has been this young man looking through the shop-window, and at the end of the movie he finally comes into the shop...

 and tries to rob the old man.  I think he shots at the old man at point blank range, but he remains unharmed and comes towards the robber.  The robber stumbles and falls into this chest on the floor.  The lid closes, and it's something like an "iron-maiden" - with long spikes.

Does this movie sound familiar to anybody?

The plot you described shares some similarities with Needful Things, but many details don't match.

@Tautologist  Nope, that's not it.  Give +1 anyway though, since that looked like an interesting movie.

You're looking for the anthology horror movie From Beyond the Grave from 1974.

Four customers purchase (or take) items from Temptations Limited, an antiques shop whose motto is "Offers You Cannot Resist". A nasty fate awaits those who cheat the shop's Proprietor (Peter Cushing).

One of the stories ends like you've described (with that groom figurine on a wedding cake being cut, resulting in an actual death), and at the very end:

Between each of the segments, a shady character (Ben Howard) is seen to be casing the shop. In the end, he enters and persuades the Proprietor to hand him two loaded antique pistols. He then tries to rob the Proprietor, who refuses to hand him any money and walks towards the thief. The thief shoots, but finds bullets cannot stop the Proprietor. Terrified, the thief staggers back, is hit by a swinging skeleton, falls into what appears to be a combination of a coffin and an iron maiden, and is spiked to death.

Here's the trailer:




Yes, this is it!  I clearly remember the robber's "accident".  Thanks!

No problem. Your ID questions are exemplary: detailed, comprehensive... If only they were all like that!
